# Is it possible to print from an Azure worker?

Tags: azure, printing

In my scenario, I will have documents stored in Azure blob storage. I'd like to be able to take those and print them when a user requests.

The setup will look something like this:

```
     Azure
      |
_____________
|     |     |
B1    B2    B3
```

Where each 'B' is a building. When a user from B2 clicks on a web app to print a document, the worker role will kick off logic to print to the designated printer in B2.

I've already set up my workers for other tasks, but I'm not sure where to start looking to set up printing. Is something like this possible?

I would like there to be as little user interaction as possible for security purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is No. In order for a Worker Role VM to print a document, it needs to connect to a printer. How will your worker role connect to a printer? What you could instead is have the user download the document through your web app on their local computer and print it from there.