# Is it possible to print through .NET code from an Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, pdf

To start off with, I am aware of this question that [seems to ask the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716678/is-it-possible-to-print-from-an-azure-worker). However I'm going to ask it again with a slight modification.

I'm working on a project to print PDF's. We have a library for PDF manipulation. We can use it to render a PDF to a file that the **System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument** object can use and print in c#. We are going to have an Azure Worker role that takes many 1-page pdf's and turns them into one large pdf, and I would like to have another Azure Worker Role that then spools that large PDF to a Windows Print Server here locally.

Since the printing part is so much slower (compared to the pdf creation/aggregation piece) I would like to be able to host it in azure to easily scale.

My initial thought was "I don't think this is even possible. How would Azure be able to know anything about my local print server." Which is the basic answer from the above similar question. But after some searching, I found some results that seem to indicate setting up a VPN Site-To-Site Tunnel or ExpressRoute Connection would let me do what I want. However I'm relatively new to Azure and the results I found are short on actual, useful, helpful details.

If it can't be done, fine, I can set up an application server locally to do the printing. But if someone has ideas or more insight on how to accomplish this I would love to hear it.

Comment: What approach did you end up using @pfunk ?

Comment: We ended up writing a service to run in the local environment that pulled the PDFs down from azure and spooled/printed them from the local environment. We WERE able to get the files to print locally from azure (using the vpn-type options available at the time) however it was so slow that it was never really a viable option (as in 1 page per minute type slow)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, I'll be looking at Universal Print in the next days, it looks like a nice alternative. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you could store PDFs into [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) like:

```
http://azureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/PDF/pdf1.pdf
```

Then you define an Azure Queue entity like:

> MyQueue(Pdf_Id, Pdf_Blob_Url)

```
MyQueue(1, http://azureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/PDF/pdf1.pdf) 
MyQueue(2, http://azureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/PDF/pdf2.pdf)
```

and submit to the [Azure Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/).

Then on your Printing server, just setup an application to check the `AzureQueue` to process the PDFs. At this point, just get the PDFs directly from Azure blob storage url to do anything you want like merging, printing,....

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the VPN / Site-To-Site  setups, here is an Idea:

You could have a small application hosted on your network that uses Service Bus Relay to expose a WCF service (this will allow incoming connections to the service from the role)

The worker role can consume this Service and then send the PDF for printing to it.

Your App would send the PDF to the printer via PrintDocument object you mentioned.

See:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/

> **What is the Service Bus relay?** The Service Bus relay service enables
>   you to build hybrid applications that run in both an Azure datacenter
>   and your own on-premises enterprise environment. The Service Bus relay
>   facilitates this by enabling you to securely expose Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF) services that reside within a corporate
>   enterprise network to the public cloud, without having to open a
>   firewall connection, or require intrusive changes to a corporate
>   network infrastructure.

Comment: The problem with this approach (which I have considered) is that the rendering/spooling of the pdf (the "expensive" part), still happens on a local appserver, which can't autoscale. This is actually probably how it will get implemented if I can't do the rendering/spooling in Azure, which I mentioned.

Comment: Can the rendering still not occur on the worker roles?  You just send the finalized PDF to the print service?  Or better, put the finalized document into blob storage, and have a queue in a work role process throttle sending to the print service by responding to messages from the queue one at a time?

Comment: By Rendering I don't mean creating the PDF. I mean the part where you send the PDF to the PrintDocument and turn the PDF into a "something" that PrintDocument can actually print. In this case an EMF. That happens in the PrintDocument.PrintPage event. Basically we give the document to PrintDcoument, call Print and it iterates through the pages and renders each page of the PDF into a graphics object on the PrintPageEventArgs and that is what is actually printed. That is the part I would like to happen in the worker role.

Comment: Ah, I see - and I suppose the PrintPage is driver dependent. which points you back at the virtual network.  Is there an advantage to needing to auto scale the production of the printable document since it is held in a printer queue anyway?

Comment: The advantage is that the spooling part is slow, compared to everything else. We have a lot of high speed printers. Creating the PDF's is fast. Aggregating the PDF's is fast. We need the spooling to be able to keep up with generating during high volume times AND keep the printer queues loaded. Having 20 jobs waiting in the printer spool is more efficient than printing a job, waiting, printing a job, waiting, etc

Comment: Coming at it from a different angle: Does the PrintPage event make many calls on the graphics object when outputting the PDF?, I did a little test on the XPS print driver and noticed iterating over 10000 DrawString has a noticeable effect on performance.  If the PDF is doing many calls on the Graphics object during print page, could you batch them onto an in memory bitmap first, and then DrawImage on the print object?  Maybe the spooling can be optimized to make the above work?